# Magento 2 Product page remove fotorama slider and display all products images one by one

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-page, fotorama-slider

In Magento 2 Product page I am trying to remove fotorama slider and display all products images one by one as below screenshot. For Configurable products it should change the dynamic values for its associated products if an.

Below is the image of current Magento 1 site.
[image]

If there are any extensions available please suggest or guide.

Comment: Kindly please share your knowledge if this is feasible or not ?

Comment: Hi, were you able to disable Fotorama Slider?

Comment: Yes, you can change accordingly to gallary.phtml. You can just add carousel slider in it if you want.